# How to FInd Google Hangouts Coversation Id

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I'm trying to find a conversation id since I want to make a Google Hangouts/Chat bot but I can find it I remember it being there before in the Url but now its gone? I'm Using the 3rd party Hangups API.I know this is a duplicate but no one answered my previous question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Method: spaces.list](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces/list) to get the list of spaces available. As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/concepts/cards#spaces) says: *A space in Google Chat is a generalization of chat rooms and direct messages.*

Comment: i am not using the official google chat api i am using a 3rd party api in python called Hangups